# Change threads to asyncio to make API calls simpler and faster

Tags: python-3.x, concurrency, python-asyncio

I wrote a script that's doing what I want but not the way I want to do it. Rather than copy it here, I'm writing an equivalent that's completely useless but illustrates the main concept. The script fetches data from an API. It does something with it. And then it posts it to another API. It's simple. Except that, rather than waiting for each API call to complete, I want to do all the calls concurrently. I can do that pretty easily with threads:

```
import requests
from threading import Thread

class WithThreads:
  facts = []
  percentages = []
  threads = []

  HEADERS = {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'API-KEY',
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'text-similarity-calculator.p.rapidapi.com'
  }

  @staticmethod
  def join_all(threads):
    """
    Join all threads in the array and clear the array.
    """
    while threads:
      thread = threads.pop()
      thread.join()

  def get_facts(self):
    """
    Calls the first API n times with different parameters. (In real life.)
    Should ideally yield.
    """
    for _ in range(10):
      thread = Thread(target=self.get_fact)
      self.threads.append(thread)
      thread.start()

  def get_fact(self):
    """
    Calls the first API once.
    """
    # May take long.
    self.facts.append(requests.get('https://catfact.ninja/fact', 
       headers=self.HEADERS).json()['fact'])
  
  def get_percentage(self, ftext, stext):
    """
    Calls the second API once.
    """
    # May take long.
    response = requests.get('https://text-similarity-calculator.p.rapidapi.com/'
                            f'stringcalculator.php?ftext={ftext}&stext={stext}',
                            headers=self.HEADERS)
    self.percentages.append(response.json()['percentage'] + '%')
  
  def get_percentages(self):
    """
    This is the main class to be called.
    Feeds the result of the first API into the second API,
    uses threads instead of asyncio.
    """
    self.get_facts()
    self.join_all(self.threads)
    first = self.facts[0]
    previous = first
    for fact in self.facts[1:]:
      thread = Thread(target=self.get_percentage, args=(previous, fact))
      self.threads.append(thread)
      thread.start()
      previous = fact
    thread = Thread(target=self.get_percentage, args=(previous, first))
    self.threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()
    self.join_all(self.threads)
    return self.percentages
```

It works, but this is wrong for a number of reasons.

First of all, it really should be using asyncio. I cannot get this to use asyncio effectively. I tried, but either the code gets really complicated or methods end up just not getting called.

Also, in order to by Pythonic, the data from the facts loop should be yielded. I don't think that threads allow that, but given that I should not be using threads anyway, it's not really an issue. asyncio should allow the data to be yielded.

In this example, I'm using two data items for the second API call. (`ftext` and `stext` are compared by the API.) In my real code, only one data item from the first API is use for each of the calls to the second API. So I'd like each response to move to the second call as soon as they are ready. asyncio should allow that too.

How can this be rewritten in order to use asyncio effectively?

Comment: `requests.get` is a blocking call, so asyncio is the wrong tool for that.  Threads are exactly what you need.  As for why you think asyncio will make your code simpler and faster, I just don't know why you would think that.  Asyncio does cooperative multitasking in a single thread, and I don't see how that would help you.  `yield` statements don't make your program "Pythonic" unless you have a logical need for them.  I think your application logic might be streamlined with ThreadPool, ThreadPoolExecutor and/or Queue.

Comment: @PaulCornelius I was reading about asyncio.Queue, and I guess I thought that it was just a more streamlined version of the regular queue. The docs say, "asyncio queues are designed to be similar to classes of the queue module. Although asyncio queues are not thread-safe, they are designed to be used specifically in async/await code." The docs for asyncio also say, "asyncio is often a perfect fit for IO-bound and high-level structured network code." But if I was just trying to do what I thought was the right thing for the wrong reason, it would explain why it didn't work.

Comment: @PaulCornelius :  "requests.get" being synchronous and blocking does not stop one of swtching to an async http library, like aiohttp or httpx.  The fact is that what `requests.get` does is exactly the sweetspot for the async paradigm, and even just using an asyncio-driven threadpool executor just to keep unsing requests in this case should have gains.